# Mobclix 4.1 SDK and iOS 3.x? Where can I download 4.0.3 SDK?

Tags: iphone, ads, mobclix

I'm trying to add Mobclix Support into my app, and I don't want to make the app only accessible by iOS 4 devices, so I'm not using iAds, but I need to know how I can get the Mobclix 4.1 SDK to work in my iPhone app for 3.x devices.  If it is not possible, I need to know where I can download the older version of Mobclix (4.0.3) which does fully support iOS 3.x devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured out that you can create apps with a base SDK higher than the minimum version, so I moved my project over to the new development tools, configured everything for Mobclix, and then went to Project > Edit Project Settings > Build > Deployment > iPhone OS Deployment Target and made sure it was iPhone OS 3.1